# Missing rac_signalForControlEvents in RAC5

Tags: ios, uibutton, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4

Now i update the ReactiveCocoa to 5(version 4.2.2) for the swift3.
But there has not api `rac_signalForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)` for UIButton,which i use in previous version

Is there anyone know? How to resolve that?

Comment: I have the same issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697384/reactive-cocoa-reactive-swift-swift-3-0-missing-methods

Answer (score 1):

Some part of the Obj-C API have been divided in another framework : ReactiveObjC.

I needed to install this framework to access these methods.

Solution :

> As stated in README (Objective-C and Swift section), those Objective-C
>   API are splitted out to ReactiveObjC framework. You need to add
>   https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveObjC as a submodule, link the
>   framework, then import ReactiveObjC.

Please see the following discussion on the issue :

https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/3197