# Reactive Cocoa / Reactive Swift - Swift 3.0 missing methods

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

Since I updated `Reactive Cocoa (RAC 5)` for `Swift 3.0` which needs `Reactive Swift` to works, I don't find events methods like `textField.rac_textSignal` on a `UITextField` for example, or `cell.rac_prepareForReuseSignal` for a `UICollectionViewCell`.

I imported both frameworks, I think the problem is that they updated the frameworks and they changed the name of the methods. But I didn't find an updated documentation for `Swift 3.0`.

I install `Reactive Cocoa / Reactive Swift` as a `submodule` in my project, not from Carthage, maybe the problem is coming from there ?

(Like that : https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#getting-started)

Can someone tell me how to solve this ?

Reactive Swift : https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift

Only have : `rac_lifetime`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts of the Obj-C API have been divided in another framework : ReactiveObjC.

I needed to install this framework to access these methods.

**Solution :**

> As stated in README (Objective-C and Swift section), those Objective-C
>   API are splitted out to ReactiveObjC framework. You need to add
>   https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveObjC as a submodule, link the
>   framework, then import ReactiveObjC.

Please see the following discussion on the issue :

https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/3197

Answer (score 0):

Please note that ReactiveCocoa 5.0 had just released its first alpha version, which includes AppKit, Foundation and UIKit extensions without dependencies on ReactiveObjC.

https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/5.0.0-alpha.1